# Define native method to sort array based on property in array

Tags: javascript, web

Been working with this simple task for a bit now and I just can't seem to figure out what the issue is. I have an array of objects, each object has a SetIndex property and I want to insert objects and maintain the array ordered by the objects Set Indices. I thought this was fairly simple but it does not seem to be working as I had expected.

The native method inserts, but the chunk that checks if the array is empty always seems to evaluate to true, and overwrites index 0 every time and does not execute the splice. I think it is something simple about JS I am missing, but I can't seem to figure it out.

```
Array.prototype.insertAtIndex = function(item) {
    for (i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if(i+1 > this.length)
        {
            if(this[i].SetIndex <= item.SetIndex && this[i+1].SetIndex  >= item.SetIndex)
            {
                this.splice(i,0,item);
            }
        }
    }
    if(this[0].length == 0);
    {
        this[0] = item;
    }
};
```

I run the following to test the function

```
item1 = {SetIndex: 0,name: 'item1'};
item2 = {SetIndex: 1,name: 'item2'};
item3 = {SetIndex: 2, name: 'item3'};
item4 = {SetIndex: 3, name: 'item4'};
item5 = {SetIndex: 4, name: 'item5'};
console.log(item1.SetIndex);
my_array = [];
my_array.insertAtIndex(item2);
console.log(my_array);
my_array.insertAtIndex(item1);
console.log(my_array);
my_array.insertAtIndex(item5);
```

I have tried using if(this[0] == undefined) as well to check if the array is empty but nothing works as I planned

Comment: is there a reason not to just implement a custom sort using the property value? i.e. `my_array.sort(function(a, b) { return a.SetIndex - b.SetIndex; });` you can sort it whenever you need to make sure they stay in order this way if you need.

Comment: Well couldn't figure out why my method wouldn't work, but instead of inserting in order I ended up just using the native Array.sort at the end that compared a.SetIndex and b.SetIndex

EDIT: I wrote this at the same time intothev01d answered, that is what I ended up doing. But if anyone knows why the original didn't work it would be appreciated

Comment: You're missing a `for(` **`var`** `i=0; i<…`!

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
for (i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    if(i+1 > this.length)
    {
         // dead code
```

the maximum of `i` (inside the loop) is `this.length-1`.  Therefore, `(i+1 > this.length)` can **never** be true.